# Proof Help: Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$. And, let $x, y, z \in A$. If $x \in y/R$ and $z \not \in x/R$, then $z \not \in y/R$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Need help with the following proof:

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$.  And, let $x, y, z \in A$.  If $x \in y/R$ and $z \not \in x/R$, then $z \not \in y/R$.

Here is the outline so far and I don't think it is correct.

This is proven through contradiction.  Suppose $x \in y/R$, $z \not \in x/R$, and $z \in y/R$.  Since $x \in y/R, yRx$, and since $R$ is symmetric, $xRy$ too.  Since $z \in y/R$, $yRz$, and since $R$ is transitive, $xRz$.  That is, $z \in x/R$.  This contradicts the hypothesis $z \not \in x/R$.

Comment: It's perfectly correct. Why were you not confident while posting this?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Well, I'm just starting to write proofs and I seem to make little mistakes here and there.  As I look at this I don't think I have the order write on the yRx statements.  Isn't it $x \in y/R$ , $xRy$ and since R is symmetric, $yRx$ instead of the other way around as in the proof?"

Comment: It does not make a difference which way you define the equivalence class, hence the way you write this statement also does not make any difference really. However, I think you have written correctly, and it is not the other way round.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks for the comment.  It takes awhile to get confident in writing proofs.  :)

Comment: It takes a good while, but as long as you practice regularly, you are certainly going to get it right. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof stated in the question is a valid proof.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/693651)

Comment: @Leucippus I am the author of the original.  I am new here so I'm curious on protocol.  I left a similar proof validation question without an answer and was asked to provide a post of this nature to close out the question.  I'm happy to retract my answer I just don't want a follow up email from another moderator asking me to post an answer to the original question.  Thanks.

Comment: When reviewing posts there are few options to use for complete clarification. As to the specifics: What is presented currently is a comment and not really an answer that expands insight to solve the question.